# Can I put an IEEE accepted journal version on Arxiv without paying Open Access fee?

Tags: arxiv, open-access, ieee, fees

I am targeting an IEEE publication that allows Traditional manuscript submission or Open Access (OA) manuscript submission. [The OA fee is $2,045.](https://signalprocessingsociety.org/publications-resources/ieee-signal-processing-letters/information-authors-spl)

1. If I decide not to pay the OA fee (ie, I go for Traditional manuscript submission), can I still put the **accepted** paper version on arXiv?
2. If 1. is positive, what are the benefits of choosing the OA submission? What can't you do with the Traditional submission that you can with the OA one?

Comment: That is up to IEEE, but I doubt they would permit it. Publishers generally have some rules about what the author can put on arXiv and still publish with them. But I don't know their specific rules

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can (and open access has nothing to do with this).

[Source](https://journals.ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/become-an-ieee-journal-author/publishing-ethics/guidelines-and-policies/policy-posting-your-journal-article/)

> **Accepted article**
> Authors may share or post their accepted article in the following locations:
>
> - Author’s personal website
> - Author’s employer’s website
> - arXiv.org
> - TechRxiv.org
> - Funder’s repository*

Note you have to include the IEEE copyright notice (given in the next section of the source).

Answer (score 1):

**Non-legal answer:**

The journals (theoretically) are there to provide editorial services as well as manage peer-review.

As such, the final product, or "accepted paper version" as you put it, is a result of work of the original authors, as well as the editor and IEEE organization. These people own the copyright and so regulate the licensing. You can't just "put it on arXiv".

**Legally speaking:**

Consult your agreement with IEEE and potentially a copyright lawyer.

Here is what [IEEE has to say](https://www.ieee.org/content/dam/ieee-org/ieee/web/org/pubs/author_faq.pdf), and a quote:

> **Can an author post his manuscript on a preprint server such as TechRxiv or ArXiv?**
>   Yes. The IEEE recognizes that many authors share their unpublished manuscripts on public
>   sites. Once manuscripts have been accepted for publication by IEEE, an author is required to
>   post an IEEE copyright notice on his preprint. Upon publication, the author must replace the
>   preprint with either 1) the full citation to the IEEE work with Digital Object Identifiers (DOI)
>   or a link to the paper’s abstract in IEEE Xplore, or 2) the accepted version only (not the IEEEpublished version), including the IEEE copyright notice and full citation, with a link to the
>   final, published paper in IEEE Xplore.

Comment: From what I read in your link, there is "accepted" and "published" version, the latter being the final product. It seems you can post the accepted version on Arxiv (as @allure points out), but not the published one. Also, it seems that IEEE provides you with the pdf of the accepted version that can be posted, indicating that the article has been accepted.  [Sec D of this source](https://www.ieee.org/publications/rights/rights-policies.html)

Comment: @dave i got confused by several different things they mention, but that sounds about right. The point is that contract with IEEE says when piece of your writing stops being just "yours"

Answer (score 0):

About point 1: the author accepted manuscript (AAM) is something which is prepared independently from IEEE and before any copyright transfer paperwork is signed. So IEEE certainly cannot forbid you from posting the AAM on arXiv or elsewhere, if you do so before signing copyright transfer paperwork. What they can do (and often will do) is require you to sign copyright transfer agreements that are incompatible with what you have already done, with the risk that they won't publish the final version of the article if you don't comply.

Note that, in some cases, your employer or funding agency may in fact be requiring you to post the AAM online under a permissive license, notwithstanding any rules from the publisher. For instance, you may be covered by the [rights retention strategy](https://www.coalition-s.org/rights-retention-strategy/) if funded by a cOAlition S funder, you may be covered by [mandatory archiving policies](https://www.coalition-s.org/rights-retention-strategy/) from your employer, etc.

To elaborate a bit on this: the point of rights retention strategies is essentially to submit the article with boilerplace acknowledgements indicating that due to funder/institutional requirements the authors will be posting the AAM online under a permissive license (e.g., CC-BY); then post the AAM online (notwithstanding any publisher rules to the contrary); then require the publisher to accommodate this in subsequent copyright transfer agreement. The idea is that if researchers are required to do this by a critical mass of funding agencies and institutions, then publishers will have no choice to accommodate it.

About point 2: the "benefit" of IEEE gold open-access is that is allows you to make sure that the publisher version of the article, with the journal formatting and publisher changes, is available as open-access -- not just the AAM.

Comment: "About point 1: the author accepted manuscript (AAM) is something which is prepared independently from IEEE" - I think journals could easily dispute the truth of this statement. It's irrelevant what the timing of the copyright transfer paperwork is, at that point in the submission process the journal has likely contributed heavily to the current version of the manuscript.

Comment: @BryanKrause: maybe, but I do not see why this means the journal could prevent the authors from posting their work. As far as I understand, the justification for publisher restrictions to the sharing of AAMs is only the copyright transfer agreement that comes afterwards.

Comment: Those agreements only make clear the rights and responsibilities of the parties; they don't say anything about the legal status of the revised manuscript at that point. The publisher is also fully within their rights to deny publication of a final manuscript version if you post even an earlier version you own completely. The most common compromise I've seen is that journals allow authors to post preprints of their pre-review submission without impacting publication. IEEE goes further and explicitly states that authors can post the "accepted manuscript" version.

Comment: Yes, I agree that the publisher can deny publication of a final manuscript version (as I think I pointed out in my answer). As for what is the most common compromise, the funding agencies of cOAlition S go further and are now asking authors to post their AAMs under CC-BY, not just for IEEE but for any publisher.

Comment: Yeah, to be clear I think your answer is mostly correct and conveys IEEE's policy correctly, but I think the "certainly cannot forbid you" bit is misleading.

Comment: PS: while this may be dependent on IEEE's goodwill and on your affiliation, there is an answer here https://lancaster.libanswers.com/faq/260287 with a contact email address to ask for permission to license your accepted manuscript under CC BY if required.